# For what value of $k$ is $f(x)=\frac{k}{(1+x^3)}$a distrib. function and what is its variance?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

> Let $X$ be a random variable with the folowing distribution function:
> $f(x)=\frac{k}{(1+x^3)}$ for all $x>0$.
>
> 1. Find a value for the constant $k$ for which $f$ will be a distribution >function.
> 2. Calculate the variance of $X$.

In **1**, I assumed that in order for $f$ to be a distribution function, I should demand $$\int_0^\infty f(x) = 1$$
Since
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{k}{(1+x^3)} = (-\frac{ln(x^2-x+1)}{6}+\frac{ln(x+1)}{3}+\frac{arctan {\frac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt{3}}}}{\sqrt{3}})|_0^\infty = \frac{2\pi}{\sqrt{27}}$$
I concluded $$k = \frac{\sqrt{27}}{2\pi}$$
in **2**, Since $Var(X) = E[(x-\mu)^2]$, (and since $\mu = \int xf(x) = 1$) I thought that $Var(X)$ should be $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{(x-1)^2}{1+(x-1)^6}dx$$

But, I think that something is wrong. These integrals get too difficult for a probabiity course.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integration to find $k$ was indeed not pleasant. I have not checked it.

The rest is easy! Note that the variance of $X$ is $E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$. The expectation of $X$ exists. Let us not compute it.

For $E(X^2)$, we need $\int_0^\infty \frac{kx^2}{1+x^3}\,dx$. This integral *diverges*.

Comment: So, what does this mean? Does it mean that the variance of $X$ does not exists? Or should we say that the variance of $X$ is $\infty$? Does the term "a random variable with intfinite variance" make sense?

Comment: You could say infinite variance.  I prefer, for no good reason, to say the variance does not exist.  Random variables with infinite variance are not uncommon. Even "mean does not exist" comes up not infrequently, though in this case the mean does exist.